# VB.Net Unable to read manifest. Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I’m having a problem when running my project, it says “Unable to write manifest  'obj\Debug\MyApp.exe.manifest' ”.

```
Error   1   Unable to write manifest 'obj\Debug\MyApp.exe.manifest'. Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.  
MyApp
```

Here is the whole error message

I already change my accounts privilege to administrator as I saw in other forum.
By the way im running visual studio in windows XP.

Comment: Does this happen even on new blank projects? Where's your project located? Try resetting the folder permission for your project.

Comment: No. This happen only on this project. I put my project on Desktop. How to reset the folder permision of my project? Im using windows XP

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/08/20/how-to-manually-reset-folder-and-file-permissions-in-windows-explorer/) should work. Alternatively, your antivirus may block the activity (new unrecognized .EXE being modified, etc), try disabling it temporarily

Comment: These are not errors you get from *running* your project.  They are compile errors.  Very nasty ones, this machine is in very poor shape.  Lets call it an opportunity, high time to upgrade from XP.